# Construction of Schauder bases on $C(X)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and let $C(X)$ be the set of continuous (bounded) real-valued functions on $X$ equipped with the usual supremum norm:
$$
\|f\|_{\infty}\triangleq \sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|.
$$
Apparently, under these conditions $C(X)$ admits a *[Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis)*.  In general, how can we construct explicitly such Schauder bases?

Comment: Semadeni published a SLN on this topic. Presumably you can find what you want there (I don't have access at the moment).

Comment: What is an SLN?

Comment: Presumably referring to these [Springer Lecture Notes](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0094629).

Comment: Yes, thanks--I thought this was common knowledge amongst maths researchers.  @John_Algorithm By the way, if you are happy to confine your attention to uncountable spaces, you can use Milyutin's theorem (just google) to reduce to the $C([0,1])$ case, where an explicit basis (actually THE Schauder basis) was already known to the polish school (see Banach's book).

Comment: You could have references in 10 seconds by Googling. Moreover, this question has been answered on stackexchange.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667251/example-of-a-basis-of-c0-1